# In Keras, what is the correct format of y_train when the output is one of eight classes using LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification, lstm

The data is related to the forearm motion recordings performing 8 possible gestures, I have an accelerometer (x,y,z), gyroscope (x,y,z) and orientation quaternion. 
I'm preparing that data to be classified and predicted using LSTM model in Keras. My doubt is about how to format correctly y_train when the X_Train is organized in batches.

The data is composed of 10 features (acceleration, gyroscope, quaternion), 71850 samples, and 9 classes (one is non-gesture, and 8 gestures).
Each gesture has a timestep window of 75 samples which is 1.25s.

My question is how to adapt y_train to match X_train.
In the following code **sf** has a shape of (71850, 10) and **gest** (71850, 1). I translate **sf** to X_train with shape (958, 75, 10) (batches, timestep, features). 
I started building y_train using One-Hot-Encoding vector having a shape (71850, 9). And here is where I am trapped. How to format y_train, to finally pass it to the LSTM model? What I understand it has to be (958, 9) 
Does that mean I just need to extract one_hot_encoding vector every 75 steps?

```py
sf, gest = readFileAndReturnData(0)
print(sf.shape, gest.shape)

num_classes = 9
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(gest, num_classes)
print(y.shape)

samples = list()
length = 75
n = sf.shape[0]
print('division:', n / length)
print('total samples', sf.shape[0])
print('sample error', sf.shape[0] % length)

# step over the size of data in jumps of 75
for i in range(0, n, length):
    # grab from i to i + length
    sample = sf[i:i + length]
    samples.append(sample)
print('minibatch samples:', len(samples))

# convert list of arrays into 2d array
X_train = np.array(samples)

print(X_train.shape)

'''
(71850, 10) (71850, 1)
(71850, 9)
total samples 71850
sample error 0
minibatch samples: 958
(958, 75, 10)
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically if your question is related to how the output shape should be for an LSTM architecture ,then it can be either a 2-D or 3-D array that depends on your return sequence argument which you have given in **model.add**(in case of keras) function.

If the return_sequence = False , then it is a 2-D array which shows (batch_size,units) which in your case will be (958,9)

but in case if you want your output to be taken after each gesture is completed then you have to set return_sequence  = True , in which case output will be(batch_size,each_gesture_completing_time_step,units) so it will be like (958,75,9)

Hope it helps!